# Azure Kafka trigger: how to receive only events after w specified offset

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-functions

How can I start reading topic messages for a specific offset or partition using Azure Trigger.

I’m building a new trigger for an existing topic but i do not want to consume all the previous messages.

Ive tried AutooffsetReset= AutoOffsetReset.Earliest or AutoOffsetReset.Latest in my cde in config file and Consumer consumes all the messages from all the offsets but this is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

There's no properties for setting specific offsets from consumer config.

If you know, or can configure, the consumer group id, then you'll need to externally use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` to first set the group offsets to a particular position before starting the trigger.